# Windows 2008 R2 DHCP server not responding to DHCP discover

Tags: dhcp, windows-server-2008-r2

I've got two Windows 2008 Enterprise R2 servers both running DNS and DHCP called cod & lobster.  DHCP is setup using the split scope option introduced with 2008 R2, whereby both servers should respond with the first response providing the lease.   Setup is as follows:

Cod
 - IP: 192.168.0.231
 - Pool: 192.168.0.101 - 192.168.0.179, exclusion for 160-179.
 - Response Delay: 0ms
 - Authorised in Active Directory (Re-authorised to confirm)
 - Windows firewall disabled while testing

Lobster
 - IP: 192.168.0.232
 - Pool: 192.168.0.101 - 192.168.0.179, exclusion for 101-159.
 - Response Delay: 1000ms
 - Authorised in Active Directory

All DHCP leases to clients are currently being issues by Lobster rather than Cod.   Packet captures with Wireshark show the following (all to broadcast address):

Client - DHCP Discover
Lobster - DHCP Offer (after 1s delay)
Client - DHCP Request
Lobster - DHCP Ack
Client - DHCP Inform

From my setup with two servers I'd expect to see a DHCP Offer coming from Cod almost immediately after the DHCP Discover.

Does anybody have any idea what would prevent the DHCP Server responding to the discover?

Comment: Try stopping the DHCP service on Lobster to test if Cod is working at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, if I stop the DHCP service on Lobster I don't get any DHCP response. I've also tried removing the DHCP server roll, restarting, then adding the DHCP role on Cod.  The DHCP service statistics don't see any DHCP discovers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to "necro" this old question but I was having the same issue and resolved it myself. I found this question when I was searching for help and figured it might be useful to someone else if I responded.

Even though I enabled DHCP on the only NIC on the server in the wizard it needed to be re-enabled in the DHCP management console after I completed the installation of the DHCP role. I, like the OP, also used WireShark and confirmed the DHCP Discovers were being issued and seen by the server, but the DHCP Service had not been enabled on the NIC by the wizard and so did not hear the Discovers.

Comment: The Binding is under IPv4 Properties, Advanced tab, Bindings button.  It took me a while to figure out where it was.